# Graph DFS detecting cycles - (supposed) counterexample

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, depth-first-search

So a DFS should detect cycles in a directed graph. If it reaches a node that has already been visited previously, i.e. it finds a back-edge, then we have a cycle.

I found a graph in which I can't see how this is the case. I know there must be a flaw in how I'm thinking, so if anyone can help me out it would be great.

So here's the graph with the adjacency list (drawing it didn't exactly work...):

> A | B
>   B | C, D
>   C | F
>   D | E
>   E |
>   F | E

Assuming the DFS starts from A, and when it gets to B, pushes C before D to the stack, then it will reach node E first, and then mark it visited. Then it will pop node C, go to F, then find E in F's adjacency list and E is already visited, thus giving a cycle. But there's really no cycle in the graph.

Where's the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: This link might help in better understanding templatetypedef's answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw here is that revisiting a node during a DFS doesn't necessarily give a back edge.  It can also give a cross edge or forward edge, which is the case here.  A back edge only occurs when the node you revisit has started being explored but has not had all of its children processed.  In this case, since E already has had all of its children processed, the edge on which it's encountered a second time isn't a back edge, so no cycle should be reported.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Follow up: What about graph A->B->C->D->A

Comment: @Jimmy "processed" in "not had all its children processed" should be taken as including processing all descendents. B is not done being processed until C has been processed, which does not happen until D has been processed. Finding the D->A edge while A has started being explored but not had all its children processed means there is a cycle.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, thank you. I figured it out. I was implementing it in C++ iteratively and I couldn't figure out a way to do the "processed" after all children had been processed. I was only able to do it after pushing the adjacent nodes to the stack, not after pushing them AND processing them, as should be. So I went for the recursive DFS and it worked out. Thanks all! :)